# How to get collection of elements in capybara cucumber

Tags: xpath, capybara

all!

Possible I have a table

```
<tabel>
    <tr><td><input type=text/></td><td><input type=text/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type=text/></td><td><input type=text/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type=text/></td><td><input type=text/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type=text/></td><td><input type=text/></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want fill them in cycle with cucumber step definition like this

```
    table.hashes.each do |hash|
      within(:xpath,"//div[@id='cycle_form']/table/tr#{table.hashes.index(hash)}") do
        fill_in("schedule_of_working_new_cycle_attributes__day", :with => hash['day'])
        fill_in("schedule_of_working_new_cycle_attributes__hour", :with => hash['hour'])
        fill_in("schedule_of_working_new_cycle_attributes__hour_night", :with => hash['hour_night'])
      end
    end
```

I get   @ Unable to find xpath "//div[@id='cycle_form']/table/tr[0]" @

How can i get collection of elements with capybara?

Comment: did you try naming your div with id="cycleform" in the html?

Comment: Is <tabel> spelled wrong in your actual code as well, or did you just misspell it when you posted it here? Because that could be your problem.

Comment: I don't try rename id attr of my div, because i have another setip like this find(:xpath,"//div[@id='cycle_form']/table").should have_css("tr td input[@type='text']") is pass. It works

Comment: I try naming my div with id="cycleform", but not result. @ Unable to find xpath "//div[@id='cycleform']/table/tr[0]" @

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the XML, so presuming it is meant to look like this:

```
<div id="cycle_form">
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This will work:

```
//div[@id='cycle_form']/table/tr[1]
```

The other thing is that XPath indexing begins at 1 not 0, so your original query wouldn't have worked any way.
Double check the input XML and correct the starting value for the iteration and it should work.

Comment: I checked and correct all. my code in  [here](http://copytaste.com/d831), but i stell get    @@Unable to find xpath "//div[@id='cycleform']/table/tr[1]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      (eval):2:in `find'
      ./features/step_definitions/fill_schedule_of_working_steps.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'.....@@